# How can I do to filter hours using Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Hello I am using Django and I have these variable :

```
a = '08:00:00'
b = '13:30:03'
```

I want to do something like this :

```
Table.objects.filter(myhour__in(a, b))
```

but it does not work...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What is `myhour`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "__time__range" lookup

```
Table.objects.filter(myhour__time__range=(datetime.time(8), datetime.time(17)))
```

[Check docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#time)